# Bitnami wordpress Problem running post install step mariadb/bin/mysql.exe

Tags: mysql, wordpress, bitnami

I am trying to install Bitnami wordpress latest version on local environment but i got this error [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gae4R.png)
even I tried older versions as well.

Problem running post-install step. Installation may not compete correctly. Error running D:\Bitnami\wordpress-6.0.2\mariadb/bin/mysql.exe "--defaults-file=D:\Bitnami\wordpress-6.0.2-0/mariadb\my.ini" "-uroot" "e SET Password=password; Delete From mysqal.user Where User="; Flush Privilleges; ";Error2002

Comment: What is "this error"? And what have you tried to resolve it? Please share all clarification in text form

Comment: now I attached a Screenshot and Description

Comment: This MariaDB post-install step connects to a newly installed and running instance of the database software and does a couple of cleanup operations. It sets a password for the database's "root" user and drops the "anonymous" user. Your error message says that the database instance is not running when it attempts this step. There may be a defect in the installation procedure. Or, maybe the whole installation needs to run with elevated privileges.